# Kirchoff's voltage law doesn't seem to hold in an experiment conducted with series resistor, diode and signal generator

Tags: experimental-physics, semiconductor-physics, experimental-technique

I've conducted an experiment to look at the electronic characteristics of a diode. This was done using a series diode, resistor ($R$) and signal generator. The signal generator was made to supply a square waveform and voltage measurements across the diode ($V_D$), resistor ($V_R$) and signal generator ($V_S$) were taken using an oscilloscope.

After gathering all the results, it was found that there seemed to be a voltage mismatch around the series circuit ($\sum V \neq 0$, which goes against Kirchoff's Law). This to me suggests there is a problem with my experimental procedure but I can't seem to explain or see why this can be. When I create a plot of IV (or ($V_R/R$) vs $V_D$), the diode characteristic given seems to match what is expected.

Could it that the oscilloscope is influencing measurements across the signal generator? Are there any other suggestions for this discrepancy? If more information is need, please don't hesitate to ask.

---

### Basic Schematic, Data, Plots and Oscilloscope Picture

Note: Linearised plot is based on the assumption that $I\approx I_0e^{qV/kT}$ for positive driving voltages, which can be rewritten as $ln(I)=ln(I_0) + (qV/kT)$.

[image: Basic Schematic]
[image: Data]
[image: Plots]
[image: Oscilloscope]

Comment: what are the values of voltage that the square wave is oscillating between?

Comment: The amplitude of the square wave was altered to get a range of Vd and I values. The amplitudes used were 0.2V, 0.3V, 0.4V, 0.5V, 0.6V, 0.7V, 0.8V, 0.9V, 1.0V, 1.1V, 1.2V, 1.3V, 1.4V, 1.5V, 1.6V, 1.7V, 1.8V, 1.9V, 2.0V, 3.0V, 4.0V, 5.0V, 6.0V, 7.0V, 8.0V and 9.0V. The wave was not shifted from 0V.

Comment: So, for example, in the last case it oscillates between -9.0Volts and 9.0Volts? Or do you mean it oscillates between 0.0 Volts and 9.0 Volts? I think you mean the former...

Comment: I meant the first example - from -9.0V to 9.0V. Another important note, I only investigated forward bias of the diode. A signal generator was used since a constant voltage source was not available for use in the experiment.

Comment: We need to see your data to make sense of this. One comment what diode did you use. If you used a light sensitive diode (photodiode or even an LED) it is possible that background light can enter this providing a DC offset.

Comment: I used the 1N4148. I'll attempt to provide the data.

Comment: Could you explain how you took the voltage measurements (a schematic of _exactly_ what you did)? If you used a scope probe with ground clips and the signal generator also tried to impose a ground level you might get strange results. You have to use a differential scope probe to measure voltage differences at arbitrary points in the circuit.

Comment: I see you added the diagram. Is the output of the signal generator ground referenced? What about the scope probe? The fact that the scope signal is not a square wave worries me. Either you have poor compensation, accidental AC coupling, or circuit overload of some kind.

Comment: I wasn't using probes. Instead, I was using stackable rod-like connectors like what is shown in the picture above. The experiment was set up such that these connectors could easily be attached to the diode, resistor and signal generator where required.

Comment: I think you might be onto something with the ground. I'm not sure how the signal generator and oscilloscope themselves were grounded, and whether they shared a common ground. I suppose this could be the source of the problem?

Comment: Absolutely. Usually one input of the scape is connected to ground and the same might be true of the signal generator. Given the strange shape of the signal I wonder whether you were even connecting both ends of the scope to the circuit... This is why I asked you to draw how the scope was connected to your circuit. Those three green wires and the black one make it look like you grounded two points in the circuit (or at least forced their voltage to be the same)!

Comment: In that particular snapshot, I believe I had both the rod connectors connected across the signal generator and the resistor. At the time when I did the experiment, I believed the shape of the waveforms was due to the signal generator being unable to create a perfect square wave - I did scale the oscilloscope to a small scale division (i.e. 20mV and 50mV).